# various objects in Object java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'd like to create class World that will have array of Object that will contain various objects.

```
public class World {
    Object obj[] = new Object[10];

    public void World() {
        this.obj[0] = new Sphere();
        this.obj[1] = new Triangle();   

        ... and so on
    }
}
```

Then in main:

```
World world = new World();
```

I'd like to use methots that are inclass of specific object.

e.g.

```
world.obj[i].methodOfSphere();
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your design is very fragile and is fraught with danger. Why this design? Your question smells of the classic [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), where you ask how do I solve the X code problem where the real solution is to forget about X and instead do Y, where you do things in a completely different way. Tell us more about the overall problem that you're trying to solve, not how you're trying to solve it, and we'll likely be able to give you a much cleaner and better solution.

Comment: Since `obj` is an `Object[]`, you'd do that painfully (casts and `instanceof`).  If you want to hold a specific object, you should do so in your array instead.

Comment: If `Sphere` and `Triangle` implement a *Shape-like* interface, use that type as the array instead. e.g. `MyShapeIfc[]`. If this is not an assignment on how to use Arrays, use a List instead. Collections are better for this sort of thing.

Comment: Use `ArrayList<BaseClassOfTriangleAndShpere>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Makoto already commented, you can verify with `instanceof` and then doing a `cast`...

```
if(world.obj[i] instanceof Sphere)
    ((Sphere)world.obj[i]).methodOfSphere();
```

However, this is not cool.

You should consider reading about `interface` to create a `behaviour` for your shapes, and override the method in the implementation...

```
public interface Shape
{
    methodSpecificToAllShape();
    method2SpecificToAllShape();
}


public class Sphere implements Shape
{
    @Override
    methodSpecificToAllShape()
    {
       //...
    }

    @Override
    method2SpecificToAllShape()
    {
        //...
    }

    /*
     * It does not stop you from adding method for a specific shape
     */
    public void method3SpecificToSphere()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Doing this, you declare your objects as a `Shape` and then the different method will be called for the correct implementation without having to do a cast.

```
Shape triangle = new Triangle();
Shape sphere = new Sphere();

triangle.methodSpecifictoAllShape();
sphere.methodSpecificToAllShape();
```

And the method specific to each shape will be executed depending on the instance.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: Ok, but in loop I have to know if its Sphere or Triangle so I have to check by instanceof if Shape is Triangle or Sphere. It's for raytracer. And for each ray I have to check if it hit triangle or sphere. (btw)

Comment: You could check with `instanceof` thats true. However, you should still use an `interface` + `implements` as your checking the `instance` of an `Object` anywhere will become painfull at long. You should also use interfaces because declaring an Object that is actually clearly a Shape as an `Object` is not representative at all. That keyword is not there for nothing, but I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: @keid: no avoid instanceof. Much better would be to consider use of a design pattern such as the Visitor Design pattern. Note that your comment is exactly the information that ***should be part of your original question***, since it is key to solving your problem, and to showing why your current approach is wrong.